# Likelihood raised to a power; how to set the power?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, posterior

Suppose ${\bf{\theta}} = (\theta_1 , \ldots, \theta_d)$ and you have a posterior as below:

$$\pi(\theta | D ) \propto L(\theta |D ) \pi(\theta)$$

Suppose we are in active learning setting and need to update the posterior each time to determine the action needed to be taken in the next step. I used MCMC to sample from the posterior. At first, the sample size is very low but it increases gradually. Because of the low sample size, the prior influence is very high.

To discount the prior effect, I raised the likelihood to a power $w$ which seems to me that it should decrease as we gather more data, and also it should be a function of inverse of variance of prior.

There are a couple of approach [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4626399/) to set the power; they integrated out the posterior to find a function of the power and then they minimized a penalized likelihood function over the power. However, my posterior is complex and I cannot integrate it out. Also, in my case $w$ is way higher than 1.

How to set $w$?

Comment: Adding a power to the likelihood does not necessarily makes MCMC harder, as e.g. when using Metropolis-Hastings.

Comment: @Xi'an It's hard before adding the power.

Comment: "At first, the sample size is very low but it increases gradually. Because of the low sample size, the prior influence is very high." @curious You say you're using MCMC but are you in fact using Gibb's Sampling? You have to discard "burn in" iterations. It is not a "small sample" issue. http://www.mit.edu/~ilkery/papers/GibbsSampling.pdf

Comment: @ AdamO Yes, I'm using Gibbs Sampling and I do discard the burn-in iterations. I don't quite understand what you mean. My application is clinical trials and the patients are enrolled gradually to the trial. At each step few patients are enrolled in the trial (say 1-3). Each time they are given the drug, their response will determine what to do next (increase the dose level, decrease or maintain) for the next cohort of patients that are going to be enrolled. The action is determined by updating the posterior each time.  So, it is indeed "small sample issue".

Answer (score 3):

You cannot arbitrarily set the likelihood to a power to offset the prior. It is basically a cheater's way of inflating the sample size. Ideal methods for decreasing the influence of a prior rather lead to values of the prior which are very close to one across the entire support or even beyond, so that the posterior is approximately proportional to the likelihood. The "cheating" aspect of the approach can be seen by noting that, in normal frequentist inference, if you set the likelihood to the power of 2, the CIs, p-values, and all summaries of uncertainty are identical to those obtained from duplicating the entire sample a second time.

In summary, unless you have a weighted likelihood, set it to the power of 1.

Comment: I understand your point.  When we gather all of the data at the very last step, we can set the power to 1 and calculate the confidence interval. Otherwise, up to the last step, my goal is exploration and with a very low sample size and no intervention, I can't do anything.

Comment: Because of the structure of the problem, I can't change the prior either

Comment: @curious Don't know what you mean by "structure of the problem". A small sample size necessarily means that the posterior should highly resemble the prior.